# How to use `syn` in regex match?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I'm trying to follow a link using `<CR>` in a markdown file.

I was giving a look into the native markdown syntax file vim ships with and found a few that use the `syn` command syntax

```
syn region markdownUrlTitle matchgroup=markdownUrlTitleDelimiter start=+(+ end=+)+ keepend contained
```

Is there any way to use a similar matching syntax and maybe pipe the match to a variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve or maybe I'm misled by the use of the `syntax` feature. The `syntax` feature is used for colorization but I understand that you would like to map `<CR>` to an action that would apply to a markdown link (like in [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki))

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not being more clear, I want to match and return the string of a given pattern, in this case a link, exactly the one you mentioned, similar to `vimwiki`, so when I press Enter, I can match this string.

Comment: But instead of using the `match()` in vimscript, I was wondering if it was possible to use a similar method to the one I mentioned, using `syn`, `start` and `end` for example.

Comment: You can use `match` but may be you could also use the result of `syntax` and catch the part of the text that is assigned to the highlighting group.

Comment: Yeah I tried but unfortunately it seems the `syntax` cannot be used in the way I'm thinking. I'll look into the more well known markdown plugins like vimwiki, wiki.vim and vim-markdown. Let's see how it goes haha.But anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that return the text of the highlighting text if it match the argument:

```
function! GetSynWord(syname)
  let l:line = line('.')
  let l:col = col('.')

  let l:stack = synstack(l:line, l:col)
  if len(l:stack) == 0
    return ''
  endif

  let l:syname = map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')[0]
  " echo l:syname
  if l:syname != a:syname
    return ''
  endif

  let l:id = l:stack[0]

  let l:start = l:col
  while l:start >= 0 
    let l:nstack = synstack(l:line, l:start)
    if len(l:nstack) == 0
      break
    endif

    let l:nid = l:nstack[0]
    if l:nid != l:id
      break
    endif

    let l:start = l:start - 1
  endwhile

  let l:end = l:col
  let l:sline = getbufline(bufnr(), l:line)[0]
  while l:end < (len(l:sline) + 1)
    let l:nstack = synstack(l:line, l:end)
    if len(l:nstack) == 0
      break
    endif

    let l:nid = l:nstack[0]
    if l:nid != l:id
      break
    endif

    let l:end = l:end + 1
  endwhile


  return l:sline[l:start: l:end - 2]
endfunction
```

The `GetSynWord('markdownLink')[1:]` will give you the markdown url if your cursor is on a markdown link.

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)